# Decoding Pin Configuration and Compatibility of a Mouse Operating in RS-422 Half-Duplex Mode

Tags: arduino, usb, serial, rs422, mouse

I have come across a system whose keyboard/mouse input claims to work on RS-422 but it has only four pins instead of the usual five pins associated with RS-422. I am seeking clarification on the pin configuration and compatibility of this mouse with RS-422 (might be half-duplex).

Upon measuring the voltages between the pins, here is what I observed:

The voltage between the first two pins is +12V.
The voltage between the second and third pins is -1V.
The voltage between the third and fourth pins is -1V.
The voltage between the first and third/fourth pins is 11V.

Considering the RS-422 standard, these voltage measurements do not align with the typical differential signaling used in RS-422.

Given this information, I have a few questions:

Is it possible for a mouse to operate on RS-422 in half-duplex mode with only four pins instead of the usual five?
If so, how would the pin configuration be set up for such a mouse?
How can I determine the compatibility of this mouse with RS-422 half-duplex mode without documentation or manufacturer information?
I appreciate any insights or guidance on understanding the pinout, functionality, and compatibility of this mouse operating in RS-422 half-duplex mode.

I am trying to use an Arduino board to act as HID and control the mouse in the Rig.

Comment: A mouse only needs to send data. From what you describe, the wires seem like 0V, supply, A,B which is all a mouse would require. It could also be half duplex. It might help if you tell us more about the system. For all we know it could be an old Mac as they used a 4 wire connection.